# How to connect a browser with guard livereload

Tags: livereload

I can't connect livereload with my browser
When I run guard command this what I get in the ouput :
[image]

normally I should have message like this :

[image]

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `bundle exec guard --debug` to see why the server is not connecting.

I also had the same issue as you. I found out that the port within my Guardfile was already in use. Try explicitly setting the host and port to the default values within the Guard file so that it looks something like this:

```
guard 'livereload' , :host=> '0.0.0.0', :port=> '35729'do

    watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html)})

end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is guard-livereload still running even after quit guard

here are what works for me:

1. kill active connection on port 35729
2. run guard --debug to verify
3. enable activereload on the page you are working on